# Excel check len string separated by comma

Tags: vba, excel

I have i string

```
15f,158,1669,187,15,156,47t
```

How to trim all data which Len <> 3

So must left

```
15f,158,187,156,47t
```

And msgbox me what is deleted

Comment: SO is not free-code service. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. _Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results._ See also: [help]

Comment: Split the string in to an array, and then iterate the elements in the array to concatenate a new string, omitting those values where `Len` is <> 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David Zemens idea.. this  should work .**Tested**

```
Sub test()
Dim str As String
Dim s() As String


str = "15f,158,1669,187,15,156,47t"
s = Split(str, ",")


For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)

If Len(s(i)) = 3 Then

t = IIf(t = "", s(i), t & "," & s(i))

End If

Next i

MsgBox (t)

End Sub
```